# How to get featured product list in home page in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, featured-product

I want **featured product list** in home page as below screenshot:-

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: You want to call on home page ?

Comment: yes i need featured product list in home page.

Comment: My question is in this block already available in your site then you want to call on home page right

Comment: This is just an image to describe my question, there is no block created.

Comment: Then you follow this tutorial http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-create-featured-product-module/

Comment: @Magento2 this is not working error is generate please update code Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'list.phtml' in module: 'Webmull_Featuredproduct' block's name: 'featuredproduct_0'